# Unexpected behaviour of glob-fs glob.readdirSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I have the following `nodejs` code. The client first calls `/api/demosounds` then call `/api/testsounds`.

```
var glob = require('glob-fs')({ gitignore: true });
app.get('/api/demosounds',function(req,res){
        var demosounds = []
        var demosoundlist = glob.readdirSync('src/assets/demosounds/*.wav');
        demosounds = demosounds.concat(demosoundlist)
        for (var i = 0; i < demosounds.length; i++) {
           demosounds[i] =  demosounds[i].replace("src/assets/","/api/static/")
        }
        demosounds = demosounds.sort()
        res.json(demosounds)
        })

app.get('/api/testsounds',function(req,res){
    var listofsounds = []
    var folderlist = ['01_sinus','02_pulse_train','03_contour_le','04_contour_fel','05_variable','06_complex_le','07_complex_fel']

    for (var x = 0; x < folderlist.length; x++){
          var testsoundlist = glob.readdirSync('src/assets/' + folderlist[x] +'/*.wav');

          listofsounds = listofsounds.concat(testsoundlist)
    }
```

When doing `glob.readdirSync('src/assets/01_sinus/*.wav')` I would expect to get only path starting with `src/assets/01_sinus/` and yet `testsoundlist` starts as the following:

```
[ 'src/assets/demosounds/electricity.wav',
  'src/assets/demosounds/phone.wav',
  'src/assets/demosounds/water.wav',
  'src/assets/demosounds/wind.wav',
  'src/assets/01_sinus/02_sin1_0065_0.16923076923076924.wav',
  'src/assets/01_sinus/04_sin1_0065_0.7692307692307693.wav',
  'src/assets/01_sinus/05_sin1_0065_1.0615384615384615.wav',
  'src/assets/01_sinus/07_sin1_0165_0.07272727272727272.wav',
```

I have no idea why this is happening :(

**UPDATE**

Somewhat closer to the problem, the code below

```
var glob = require('glob-fs')({ gitignore: true });
var folderlist = ['01_sinus','02_pulse_train','03_contour_le','04_contour_fel','05_variable','06_complex_le','07_complex_fel']
for (var x = 0; x < folderlist.length; x++){
          console.log((glob.readdirSync('src/assets/' + folderlist[x] +'/*.wav').length))
      }
```

Outputs this, as if `glob` would remember the previous globs.

```
49
98
147
196
245
294
343
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't seem to be maintained anymore and there is a hanging [issue](http://%20https://github.com/micromatch/glob-fs/issues/25) with exactly the same problem, so it seems like this is a bug.

A solution is to simply use [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob), `glob.sync()` in this case.